# Windows 7 - Error using PHP + ODBC for PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, windows-7, odbc

I'm trying to connect PHP to a PostgreSQL database via ODBC.
I'm doing the same for MySQL databases and everything works OK.

I'm using the following code:

```
$connect = odbc_connect('PT_blala','','');
$result = odbc_exec($connect, 'select * from data limit 10');
$json = array();
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
    $json[] = $row;     
}

echo json_encode($json);    
odbc_close($connect);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.1", user "postgres", database "PPCDB", SSL off , SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in...

Any help? :(

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you need to [edit the `pg_hba.conf` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), which controls client connections to PostgreSQL.

(With MySQL, you had to grant access to a user on a host, with or without a password.  This setup is analogous.)